# Splitting string data in java with white spaces

Tags: java, string, split, whitespace, string-concatenation

I have a string `xyz a z`. How to split it into `xyz az`. That is splitting the string into two parts taking first white space as the split point. Thanks

Comment: Could you share your thoughts on how you'd go about it?

Comment: you mean to loop through the string, and for each character check if its first space, if first white space is found store in one string and remaining in another by concatenating ?

Comment: @user1002448 - split splits the entire String based on whitespaces... I was asking you to split it first, take out the first element, add a whitespace and add the remaining elements ... I think kapep's answer is the one you should look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String givenString = "xyz a z";
String[] split = givenString.split(" ");
StringBuffer secondPart = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
    secondPart.append(split[i]);
}
StringBuffer finalPart = new StringBuffer();
finalPart.append(split[0]);
finalPart.append(" ");
finalPart.append(secondPart.toString());
System.out.println(finalPart.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with the second limit parameter. Use a limit of `2`.

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times

Comment: Will this split the string only once with delimiter as whitespace?

Comment: @Octopus yes, it will split the string only once, at the first occurence of the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
public static void main(String []args){
      String a= "xyz a z";
      String[] str_array=a.split(" ");
      System.out.print(str_array[0]+" ");
      System.out.println(str_array[1]+str_array[2]);

     }
```

Comment: It will show xyz on one line and az on another... use print with " "

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  String Str = new String("xyz a z");
    for (String retval: Str.split(" ", 2)){
     System.out.println(retval);
```

Comment: Second parameter in split method decides

Comment: Good, but forgot to remove space between *a* and *z* in second element

Answer (score 0):

You need to use String.split with limit of 2 as it will be applied (n-1) times, in your case (2-1 = 1 ) time

So it will consider first space only.

But still you will get the result as `xyz` and `a z`, you will still have to get rid of that one more space between `a z`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String path="XYZ a z";
String arr[] = path.split(" ",2);
String Str = new String("xyz a z");
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(" ","").trim();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
          for(String s : arr) {
               builder.append(s);
               builder.append(" ");
           }
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

In the for loop you can append a space between two arrays using `builder.append(" ")`.